# global variables are crashing firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I got this strange behavior in Firefox 33.0 (Ubuntu 12.04): after some bug in the code, all other Firefox tabs don't display anything right, and I need to close Firefox and open it again.

Looks like the global variables (NFilhos and SomaFilhos) are not being properly stored between functions? The error happens after I resize the window (thus in the resizeCanvas function). I reduced the code to a minimum:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Is this a bug?</title>
</head>
<body onload="start()" onresize="resizeCanvas()" style="overflow: hidden">
<canvas id="tree" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Seu navegador não suporta o recurso "canvas" do HTML 5.
</canvas>
</body>
<script>
var canv = document.getElementById("tree"); 
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
var NFilhos = [];
var SomaFilhos = [];

function start() {
    alert("start");
    SomaFilhos[0] = 10;
    // ... read text file from server, prepare data...
    resizeCanvas(); // draws the data the first time
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    alert("resize"); // just to see where I am 
    canv.width  = window.innerWidth;
    canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    alert("no error"); // just to see where I am 
    NFilhos[0] = SomaFilhos[0]; // error?
    //alert(NFilhos[0]);            
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I just modified your alert() to show `SomaFilhos[0]` and it shows up as 10 no problems

Comment: It worked for me on Ffx-33 in MacOS, except all the variable names are mysteriously in Portuguese....

Comment: Calling a function directly on resize is a bad idea (and using `alert` inside of it even more so – use `console.log` to make debug outputs instead) – the `resize` event fires multiple times during the process of resizing the window. You should apply a technique to delay execution of the function, similar to what it is described for the `scroll` event here: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Yeah, you need to throttle the resize event, using something like underscore's throttle method http://underscorejs.org/#throttle. Otherwise the function is executed too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body onload="start()" onresize="_.debounce(resizeCanvas(), 200)" style="overflow: hidden">
<canvas id="tree" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Seu navegador não suporta o recurso "canvas" do HTML 5.
</canvas>
</body>
```

You need to debounce the event, so it's not firing every millisecond. Underscore's throttle or Underscore's debounce methods are what you need here depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Elise. I need to draw my stuff again after the screen is resized, how do I join your code with mine? I didn't get it.

Comment: can you help me more, please?

Comment: you are abusing the onresize event and that is why your browser is crashing

Comment: I couldn't manage to make it work, but I'm doing the program different now and the error is gone. Thank you anyway.